# How to get R^2, F-statistics, and p-value for pooled models with imputed data?

Tags: r, regression, r-mice

I have estimated regression models with imputed data using mice.

```
model1 <- with(imp, lm(outcome~ predictor1+ predictor2+ predictor3+ predictor4))).
```

In the output I get some information with

```
summary(pool(model1), conf.int = TRUE)
```

like estimate, standard error and p-value. Now I'd like to know the F-value and R^2 of the whole model.

For R^2 I found the following code: `pool.r.squared(model1)`. But I'm still looking for a code to show the F-value. Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

Conventional F-statistics we get by averaging the F-values from an `anova`, *compare:*

```
mean(anova(aov(bmi ~ hyp + chl, nhanes))[, 4], na.rm=TRUE)
summary(lm(bmi ~ hyp + chl, nhanes))$fstatistic[1]
```

For pooled analyses, we may use `miceadds::mi.anova` to get both R^2 and F-statistic.

```
library('miceadds')
nul <- capture.output(
  aov_fit <- miceadds::mi.anova(mi.res=imp, formula="bmi ~ hyp + chl" )
)
```

<sup>(The `capture.output` isn't necessarily needed but prevents the console from cluttering.)</sup>

The desired information is now stored in the object `aov_fit`.

```
aov_fit$r.squared  ## R-squared
# [1] 0.1158705

(fval <- mean(round(aov_fit$anova.table$`F value`, 2), na.rm=TRUE) ) ## F-statistic
# [1] 0.97

df_mod <- aov_fit$anova.table$df1[- nrow(aov_fit$anova.table)]  ## DF model
df_res <- el(fit$analyses)$df.residual  ## DF residual
c(df_mod, df_res)
# [1]  1  1 22
```

The model p-value can be calculated by a right-tailed test using the distribution function for the F distribution `pf()`.

```
pf(q=fval, df1=sum(df_mod), df_2=df_res, lower.tail=FALSE)  ## p-value
# [1] 0.3947152
```

We now could use `sprintf` to resemble somewhat the GOF metrics of `lm()`:

```
sprintf('Pooled R-squared: %s', round(aov_fit$r.squared, 4))
# [1] "Pooled R-squared: 0.1159"

tmp <- aov_fit$anova.table
sprintf('Pooled F-statistic: %s on %s and %s DF,  p-value: %s', 
        mean(round(tmp$`F value`, 2), na.rm=TRUE), 
        round(sum(tmp$df1[- nrow(aov_fit$anova.table)]), 2),
        round(el(fit$analyses)$df.residual, 2),
        format.pval(pf(fval, sum(df_mod), df_res, lower.tail=FALSE)))
# [1] "Pooled F-statistic: 0.97 on 2 and 22 DF,  p-value: 0.39472"
```

### Update

To get the *r<sup>2</sup><sub>adj.</sub>*, we could use the usual formula,

```
adjR2 <- \(r2, n, p) {
  1 - (n - 1)/(n - p - 1)*(1 - r2)
}

adjR2(aov_fit$r.squared, nrow(nhanes), sum(aov_fit$anova.table$df1, na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] 0.03549512
```

where n=number of observations, p=number of parameters.

---

*Data:*

Using the `nhanes` data set of the `mice` package.

```
library('mice')
set.seed(42)
imp <- mice(nhanes, m=100, printFlag=FALSE)
fit <- with(data=imp, exp=lm(bmi ~ hyp + chl))
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked perfectly, thanks. Now I'm wondering if there's also a possibility to get the p-value of the F-statistic, so I know if the whole model **significantly** explains some of the variance in my data.

Comment: @lanmi Thanks for your good questions. Please see updated answer for p-value.

Comment: I've got a follow-up question. Is it also possible to estimate adjusted R^2 this way?

Comment: @lanmi See [here](https://www.statology.org/adjusted-r-squared-in-r/) how r^2 adj. is calculated and the update to my answer.