# p-Value for F-Statistics, pooled multiple linear Regression

Tags: r, regression, r-mice

I calculated the F-Value for pooled linear regression using miceadds::mi.anova.

I used the code from the post [How to get R^2, F-statistics, and p-value for pooled models with imputed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73471013/17303805) from @lanmi answered by jay.sf.

```
library('miceadds')
nul <- capture.output(
  aov_fit <- miceadds::mi.anova(mi.res=imp, formula="Y ~ A + B" )


(fval <- mean(round(aov_fit$anova.table$`F value`, 2), na.rm=TRUE) )
```

This works fine

I want to calculate the p-Value as follwing:

```
df_mod <- aov_fit$anova.table$df1[- nrow(aov_fit$anova.table)] 
df_res <- el(fit$analyses)$df.residual  
c(df_mod, df_res)

pf(q=fval, df1=sum(df_mod), df_2=df_res, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

But the result is:

```
df_res <- el(fit$analyses)$df.residual
Error in el(fit$analyses) : object 'fit' not found
```

Has anyone the same problem? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: An F-statstic is meaningless without some better description of the problem. You should review your statistics texts to understand the meaning of an inferential statstic.

Comment: As the error says, you’re referencing an object called `fit`, but haven’t created anything called `fit` in your code. Did you mean `aov_fit`?